# Android slide LinearLayout till inner reach bottom

Tags: android, animation, slide

How to slide panel to bottom till panel inner layout reaches bottom of the screen. Then stop animation. All panel layouts are dynamic height. Static values must not be used.
I use:

```
  public void slideDown(Context context, LinearLayout ln){
        Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_down);
        ln.startAnimation(slide_down);
    }
```

and

```
slideDown(getContext(), myLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to slide a linearLayout to the bottom of the screen,  and stop the animation when the bottom of the lineaLayout "touches" the bottom of the screen. Here is how I do it :

```
 public void slideDown (View movableView,View rootView){
    //rootView is the Layout placed as root in your xml
    float screenBottom = rootView.getBottom()/2; //real bottom of the screen
    float viewHeight = movableView.getHeight();
    movableView.animate().translationYBy(screenBottom - viewHeight).setDuration(1000).start();
}
```

Comment: No, In linearLayout I got another layout containing text. I want animation to stop when inner layout bottom touch bottom for the screen